# Feature request for OP to post an answer that forwards the credit another user's account

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer

It'd be a nice feature if SO can allow an OP to post an answer, but credit another user for the answer. I often get a lot of help from another user's comment, or through offline contact with another user. Then I post an answer to close the question, but it is actually the answer given to me from another user's help or comment.

[Here is an example](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/tramp-ssh-login-does-not-prompt-for-password), where a user commented on my question to contact him over email for specialized help with the tool's internal dev-team, and we resolved the issue. Email was quite necessary because it allowed us to share some private information that also included attachments of debug logs that were too large for a paste bin or quote in the SO post. It also allowed me to get in touch with the actual development team (in this case Emacs Tramp).

When the issue was resolved, the user who helped me over email did not follow up with an SO answer, so I posted it and tagged him. Ideally, I would have preferred to post it as his account or forward the correct answer tag to his account.

Perhaps this feature can be added, or an equivalent already exists?

---

UPDATE:

I am interested in crediting the user with their answer because the user is temporarily unable to access SO - they can only access their email. For example, I replied back to the user over email and suggested that he post his emailed answer on SO, or take my version of his answer and repost it with his account. When I contacted this user, he replied back describing that he was only able to access his email and could not access SO due to extreme circumstances (ie a hospitalization, accident, etc). That is why I thought it would be a thoughtful feature to post an answer, with the ability of the user to accept it later and receive the credit (only if they wish). Otherwise, I suppose the answer would just remain under my account (with an `@` tag crediting the user), or in the community wiki.

Moreover, it would be nice if I still got a little credit (ie +2) if the user decides to 'own' the answer. The credit could be for taking their comment and re-wording it into an answer.

Comment: This kind of "credit" already exists and is *required* by the site license.  The SA-by-CC license demands that you use attribution, post a link to the user's profile and a link to the user's post or comment.   The license does not consider alternatives acceptable.

Comment: In addition to what Hans suggested, if you want to keep your conscience really clean then you can check the little checkbox under your answer to make it community wiki ("CW"). This means any up votes don't go on your rep total, i.e. you are not gaining rep for someone else's answer (even though they never bothered to post it).

Comment: What if the answer gets downvotes? Posting answers is risky.

Comment: I updated my question which elaborates on the situation a bit more. Although the situation is exceptional, I think the feature could be useful for such cases. In short, the feature would be an optional 'accept' button that the user can select to 'own' the suggested answer that I have proposed and credited to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a nice thought, but it would open up loads of new complexities, problems, and ways to abuse the system.

Reputation points are a fleeting and arbitrary measure, and as a general rule, one shouldn't worry too much about it.

On the same basis, it is not terribly important that a user's input is rewarded by points with 100% certainty.

During every serious SO user's career, they will occasionally gain way too many points for no effort at all, or for a completely trivial or even incorrect answer.

At other times, they may work three hours on a brilliant answer and gain a meager upvote or two. Point is, it's not that important either way.

If you want to reward someone's help, encourage them to post an answer of their own as karma_geek points out above, and/or give them credit in your own answer!

Answer (score 7):

You could have requested the person to post his advice as an answer.

I have [already done it once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746394/getting-error-unable-to-instantiate-activity), where someone's comments turned out to be really helpful, and so I requested the person to post an answer (through a comment, which I deleted after he posted the answer). I also edited in the useful points from all his comments to make it more useful for future readers.

Currently there is no such feature to give credits to another user, so for the meantime you can notify the user (@user) through comments to add an answer.